# how to draw a specific image which van move on screen?

Tags: java

Actually i am making a game. but i am stuck in drawing image e.g i want to draw a spider which should continuously move up and down on screen. i am using graphics class with square and oval class. but when it comes to draw spider on square or oval instead of fillRect or fillOval i don't pass.

here is what iam doing again and again

```
   public void draw(Graphics surface) {
         // Draw the object
         surface.setColor(color);

             try{ 
               File f = new File( "C:\\Users\\kk\\Desktop\\7.gif");
                   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);

                   // surface.drawImage(img,0,0,1360,740,null);
               surface.drawImage(img, 7, 1,null  );
        } 
        catch( Exception e )
       {}

        //surface.fillRect(x - size/2, y - size/2, size, size);
```

Comment: are you reading the file every time when the screen refreshes? and do you use constant position?

Comment: Lookup some tutorials on google for this. Don't have SO as the first point of contact. Although there are bright people, this isn't a place where one can just come along and be like 'Yo, I didn't do research. Fix it. In fact, make the whole program for me.' SO is a place to exchange help from one to another, typically with problems that are difficult to solve. SO is **NOT** a place for the same questions to be asked time and time again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to read file every time when there's a need to render on the screen, so make a field:

```
private BufferedImage img;

public <constructor>(){
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\kk\\Desktop\\7.gif"));
}
```

and iterate the position:

```
private int x, y;

public void draw(Graphics surface) {
    surface.drawImage(img, x, y, null);

    /* if you have 2 methods: rendering and updating,
    better move it to this updating one */
    x += speed * time;
}
```

**EDIT** this is only a kind of pseudo-code, it won't work, but there's included the idea of the solution of your problem